# How to define a custom function that returns value of a field in an unsaved form

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, expression, qgis-custom-function

Filter expression builder in QGIS 2.8 allows us to define custom functions using python. I'm intrested would it be possible to define a function which returns a value of a field in an unsaved form that is currently being filled. I would like to use this output in a filter expression for value relation.

(see: [Limiting available values in dropdown field of QGIS form according to value selected in previous field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153982/qgis-forms-how-to-limit-available-values-in-a-dropdown-field-according-to-value))

Possibility of reading the contents of unsaved fields is mentioned in theese two posts, but i lack the knowledge of python to adapt it to purpose mentioned above:

[QGIS Value Map Edit Widget with properties dependent on another field](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68173/qgis-value-map-edit-widget-with-properties-dependent-on-another-field?rq=1)

[How to automatically populate fields instantly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67391/how-to-automatically-populate-fields-instantly/67395#67395)

If this is not overly complicated i would be very gratefull for an example of code i could addapt to my purpose.