# How to input python code for custom field edit method in QGIS 2.16? -or - Where is "init function"?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I am trying to implement the python code suggested as an answer to this question: [QGIS Custom Form: “Other” category in combo box replaced by line edit [closed]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91308/qgis-custom-form-other-category-in-combo-box-replaced-by-line-edit) I have the same goal as that question: to have an edit widget for data entry that starts as a dropdown menu (using value map) then change to a text line edit if the user selects "Other" from the menu. I am experienced with QGIS but new to python coding.

I put the code in a text editor and saved as FillForm.py. Then it seems I should in the layer properties type into the Init Function line edit: FillForm.formOpen. I went to the layer properties and couldn't find the Init function line edit. **What should I do with this code to get QGIS to implement it?**

My layer general properties look like this:
[image]
There isn't a text line edit called "Init function," so I don't know where to type FillForm.formOpen.

Instead I tried inputting the code as an action.
[image]
But when I select "Other" from the dropdown menu for the field "SiteName" it doesn't switch to a text edit line like I wanted it to. Now I have the option to run this action from the Identify Results menu
[image]

Running the action gives me an error
[image]

Comment: Your trying to use an action to listen for a drop down change on the SiteNamefield.currentIndexChaged.current(Other) field/control?  I do not think actions are meant for that type of event listener functionality.  Are you just wanting to get the value from the SiteNamefield within your action?

Comment: I'm trying to set up the data entry for the SiteName field. It is currently set up with a value map widget so that there is a dropdown menu to enter the site name. I want the value map widget to change to a text edit widget when I select the value "Other." I am completely new to using python in QGIS, and I cannot figure out where to put the code.

Comment: I'm not sure if that type of feature can be done in a python action (change ui control types from combo to text edit).  However I do know it can be done if you create your own custom plugin/.ui and create the .ui in QT Designer and add the back end python logic for your desired control logic switch.

Comment: The other posts that I linked to suggested that I could save python code in a file next to the QGIS project and call that code by putting a function in a box called "Init function." The init function box is not where they said it would be; does it still exist in 2.16? Or is this a feature that has been removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python init function was moved from layer general properties to layer field properties. This change happened in QGIS 2.14.[image]