# Possible to set an attribute field to update automatically based on another field?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, update, dynamic

If I have 2 attribute columns and I wish to change certain values, is it possible for the second attribute column to automatically update its values based on an expression?

Example:

```
Age |  Status
10  |  Child
14  |  Child
```

If I change the `Age` from *14* to *18*, I would like the `Status` to automatically change from *Child* to *Adult*, so it would look like the following:

```
Age |  Status
10  |  Child
18  |  Adult
```

I must only be able to do this within QGIS and without the use of database functionalities such as PostGIS/SpatiaLite etc. I've looked at **Value relations** but that only seems to provide drop-down box for the user to select the relating columns. I've also looked at **Relation Reference** but it won't allow me to select a "Relation" (not even sure what Relation Reference actually does).

Please advise?

I am using QGIS 2.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is available starting from QGIS 2.6 and is called *Virtual Field*. Just create a new attribute, select "Virtual Field" and insert the expression used to calculate the new column.

For your case:

```
CASE WHEN "Age" < 18 THEN 'Child' ELSE 'Adult' END
```

You can use a recent nightly build / test build to use this new feature.

The value relation and relation reference widgets are used to show attributes from a first table (layer) on a second table.

Comment: Almost seems as if QGIS 2.6 is the Holy Grail for all my problems! Thank you Matthias, I will test this with the new build.

Comment: @Joseph, I had quite the same problem (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107090/auto-populate-field-as-concatenation-of-other-fields) recentely and solved it with QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 by setting up a custom form. In a python script for this form I used the `field.textChanged` method  to update one field based on a change in another field.. However, this cool new 'virtual field' is much more handy!

Comment: Awesome @Kay, that's an interesting alternative. I will have to try it sometime as it can help me learn more about python. But yes, I am also looking forward to seeing the attributes of layers and joined-layers update automatically!