# QGIS Autofill Column help?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I'm working on a soil project and I am trying to add a new field that is called Drainage which is correlated to all of the different soil types (which is a different field). Is there an easy way to have information from one field be interpreted into another field?

For example, I have a soil type that is called 110D and I would like to find out if there is a easy way for QGIS to understand that since it is 110D, then it should auto fill the next field with a drainage classification.

Comment: Have you checked http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67391/how-to-automatically-populate-fields-instantly? There you'll find a possible answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual field and conditional CASE statement

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Scrennshot2]

[image: Screenshot3]